# How to keep the concurrent between database and web page?

Tags: javascript, java, oracle, spring-mvc, tomcat

Hypothesise there are two user are using one page. There is a "select" element in the page which get data from the server by Ajax. Now, one user select one record in the select box and try to insert it and other values into the database. But the terrible things is the record already be deleted by another user for some reason. The first user will
re-insert the record just deleted.

More specifically, a select box look likes:

```
<select>
  <option>Birmingham</option>
  <option>Bradford</option>
  <option>Bath</option>//got deleted
</select>
```

The user will choose a nonexistent record.

Are there any ways to keep the concurrent between database and web page? Or just ignore it, prompt the user "insert failure". Or maybe wait until they realize press "F5" to reload the hold page.
Maybe all these problems havs already been solved?

I am using Spring+Spring MVC+Mybatis and Tomcat to develop. Any direction or idea will be a great help, thanks a lot in advanced!!!

Comment: Need more details or more focus.  Check out Optimistic Locking: https://sofienebk.medium.com/optimistic-locking-in-java-c29b0fe4bac

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize the page content of different users' CRUD operations? You may try the *server-sent events* API or just AJAX polling that query every seconds whether there were changes, see documents at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: Websocket is probably the best tool for this job, because you keep a persistent connection between the *client* and the server. It's up to you on the server-side to figure out how to communicate between the two users. Maybe "broadcast" important changes like this to all connected users?